# What is the A in the Accumulation and Amount functions for the value of investments?

Tags: interest-rate

A number of interest functions, such as the accumulation function and the amount functions include an *A* (sometimes capitalized, sometimes not).  Could someone tell me what the *A* represents?  Here's an example:  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually one can think of [$a(t)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulation_function) as some form of interest.

So, we can normalize some initial investment to 1 so that:
$$a(0) = 1 $$

letting $k$ denote some initial investment, we can have that the value of $k$ at time $t$ is give by your formula:

$$A(t)= ka(t)$$

So, for example, if you invest k=10, assume an interest rate $i=5$% and compounding interest, then ten periods after you invest your money, $k$ is worth:

$$A(10,k) = 10*(1+.05)^{10}$$

Comment: Thanks, but my question was a little (or a lot) more basic.  from your last illustration, it sounds like you're saying _a_ is the final value, or what _k_ is worth after applying the interest over time.  Is that right?  And if so, is there any difference between a capital _A_ and lowercase _a_?  Or is the difference just to show that you're referring to different values and not the same one appearing twice?  --- And I noticed that you edited the last line of your formula to capitalize the _a_.  Is that just formatting?  Or would the formula have a different meaning without the correction?

Comment: I made a typo that was likely confusing. I have fixed it. Capital A(t) is the value of your initial investment after $t$ periods whenever yo u fade interest rate $i$. Think of little a(t) then as some interest rule. If you click my hyperlink, you will visit a wiki on the subject that offers several examples of what a(t) might be. Another way to think of a(t) is the rule governing how your initial investment $k$ evolves over time.

Comment: So the _a_ has no meaning by itself? Like _k_ or _t_?

Comment: It does have meaning. Its general definition is that it is the rule governing how the value of your initial investment evolves over time. However, the exact definition of $a(t)$ - compounding or simple interest rates, for example - is contextually specific.

Answer (score 0):

A(t) represents the amount function, while a(t) represents the accumulation function.

Definition 1.1.1: The accumulation function, denoted by a(t), gives the accumulated value at time t of an original investment of 1 at time 0.

Definition 1.1.2: The amount function, denoted by A(t), gives the accumulated value at time t of an original investment of k at time 0.

Comment: A(t) = a(t), when k (your initial investment) equals 1; otherwise, A(t) = k * a(t), where k is your initial investment at time t = 0